# How to update time-stamp every second to stdout of iPerf command

Tags: iperf

I'm performing iperf between two terminals and able to get the output as follows:

```css
2017-01-09 16:43:03: Connecting to host 192.168.234.2, port 5201
2017-01-09 16:43:03: [  4] local 192.168.234.1 port 36544 connected to 192.168.234.2 port 5201
2017-01-09 16:43:03: [ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr  Cwnd
2017-01-09 16:43:03: [  4]   0.00-1.00   sec   553 KBytes  4.53 Mbits/sec    1   29.7 KBytes
2017-01-09 16:43:03: [  4]   1.00-2.00   sec   499 KBytes  4.09 Mbits/sec    1   26.9 KBytes
2017-01-09 16:43:03: [  4]   2.00-3.00   sec   515 KBytes  4.22 Mbits/sec    0   32.5 KBytes
2017-01-09 16:43:03: [  4]   3.00-4.00   sec   508 KBytes  4.16 Mbits/sec    1   31.1 KBytes
2017-01-09 16:43:03: [  4]   4.00-5.00   sec   496 KBytes  4.07 Mbits/sec    1   26.9 KBytes
2017-01-09 16:43:03: [  4]   5.00-6.00   sec   515 KBytes  4.22 Mbits/sec    0   33.9 KBytes
2017-01-09 16:43:03: [  4]   6.00-7.00   sec   513 KBytes  4.21 Mbits/sec    1   31.1 KBytes
2017-01-09 16:43:03: [  4]   7.00-8.00   sec   495 KBytes  4.05 Mbits/sec    1   28.3 KBytes
2017-01-09 16:43:03: [  4]   8.00-9.00   sec   501 KBytes  4.10 Mbits/sec    1   32.5 KBytes
2017-01-09 16:43:03: [  4]   9.00-10.00  sec   513 KBytes  4.20 Mbits/sec    0   32.5 KBytes
2017-01-09 16:43:03: - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
2017-01-09 16:43:03: [ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr
2017-01-09 16:43:03: [  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  4.99 MBytes  4.18 Mbits/sec    7             sender
2017-01-09 16:43:03: [  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  4.97 MBytes  4.17 Mbits/sec                  receiver
2017-01-09 16:43:03: iperf Done.
```

Now the problem is time-stamp stays same up to end. Can anyone suggest me how to update the time-stamp every second?

Comment: what is the iperf command you are using ?

Answer (score 5):

You have to install "moreutils".

> sudo apt-get install moreutils
>
> iperf -c [server_ip] -i 1 -u -b 1G -t 5 | **ts**

```
May 31 10:28:00 ------------------------------------------------------------
May 31 10:28:00 Client connecting to x.x.x.x, UDP port 5001
May 31 10:28:00 Sending 1470 byte datagrams
May 31 10:28:00 UDP buffer size:  208 KByte (default)
May 31 10:28:00 ------------------------------------------------------------
May 31 10:28:00 [  3] local y.y.y.y port 53225 connected with x.x.x.x port 5001
May 31 10:28:01 [ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
May 31 10:28:01 [  3]  0.0- 1.0 sec  96.9 MBytes   812 Mbits/sec
May 31 10:28:02 [  3]  1.0- 2.0 sec  96.9 MBytes   813 Mbits/sec
May 31 10:28:03 [  3]  2.0- 3.0 sec  96.9 MBytes   813 Mbits/sec
May 31 10:28:04 [  3]  3.0- 4.0 sec  97.0 MBytes   814 Mbits/sec
May 31 10:28:05 [  3]  0.0- 5.0 sec   485 MBytes   813 Mbits/sec
May 31 10:28:05 [  3] Sent 345642 datagrams
May 31 10:28:05 [  3] Server Report:
May 31 10:28:05 [  3]  0.0- 5.0 sec   484 MBytes   812 Mbits/sec   0.001 ms  443/345641 (0.13%)
```